# Saving a product gives SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento-2.1

When saving a product that is already existing in the description the product is giving a weird error on the database:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or 


update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT 


CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY 


(`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` 


(`attribute_set_id`) ON DELET), query was: UPDATE 


`catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `type_id` = ?, 


`sku` = ?, `has_options` = ?, `required_options` = ?, `created_at` = 


'2017-11-01 20:36:00', `updated_at` = '2017-11-03 16:48:30' WHERE 


(`entity_id`=162)
```

What is going wrong and where can I resolve this? It is not happening for all products but just for certain products in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error, in my case this error occur when I was trying to assign attribute set to a product which is not exist. So please check if Attribute set exist or not which you are trying to assign to your product.

Or check your max_input_vars value and update it to 3000 or 5000, if it is less.